# I get an error while using jmeter SaveService.saveTree to save the test as jmx file

Tags: java, jmeter

I wanted to switch from jmx files to code in Java, so I found some example code at [Octoperf.com](https://octoperf.com/blog/2023/03/29/jmeter-in-code/#additional-elements) and tried to run it (I only entered different location for jmeter):

```
import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.ResponseAssertion;
import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.gui.AssertionGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments;
import org.apache.jmeter.config.gui.ArgumentsPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.LoopControlPanel;
import org.apache.jmeter.control.gui.TestPlanGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.extractor.json.jsonpath.JSONPostProcessor;
import org.apache.jmeter.extractor.json.jsonpath.gui.JSONPostProcessorGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.gui.HttpTestSampleGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampler;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.ResultCollector;
import org.apache.jmeter.reporters.Summariser;
import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleSaveConfiguration;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestPlan;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup;
import org.apache.jmeter.threads.gui.ThreadGroupGui;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class JmeterBasicTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Create the Jmeter engine
        StandardJMeterEngine jm = new StandardJMeterEngine();

        // Set some configuration
        String jmeterHome = "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jmeter/5.6.2";
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome(jmeterHome);
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterHome + "/libexec/bin/jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();

        // Create a new hash tree to hold our test elements
        HashTree testPlanTree = new HashTree();

        // Create a sampler
        HTTPSampler httpSamplerOne = new HTTPSampler();
        httpSamplerOne.setDomain("octoperf.com");
        httpSamplerOne.setPort(443);
        httpSamplerOne.setPath("/blog/2023/02/22/jmeter-logging/");
        httpSamplerOne.setMethod("GET");
        httpSamplerOne.setName("HTTP Request One");
        httpSamplerOne.setProtocol("https");
        httpSamplerOne.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSampler.class.getName());
        httpSamplerOne.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());

        // Create another sampler
        HTTPSampler httpSamplerTwo = new HTTPSampler();
        httpSamplerTwo.setDomain("octoperf.com");
        httpSamplerTwo.setPort(443);
        httpSamplerTwo.setPath("blog/2023/01/16/uncommon-performance-testing/");
        httpSamplerTwo.setMethod("GET");
        httpSamplerTwo.setName("HTTP Request");
        httpSamplerTwo.setProtocol("https");
        httpSamplerTwo.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, HTTPSampler.class.getName());
        httpSamplerTwo.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, HttpTestSampleGui.class.getName());

        // JSON Post Processor
        JSONPostProcessor jsonExtractor = new JSONPostProcessor();
        jsonExtractor.setName("JSON Extractor");
        jsonExtractor.setRefNames("foo");
        jsonExtractor.setJsonPathExpressions("$.title");
        jsonExtractor.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, JSONPostProcessor.class.getName());
        jsonExtractor.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, JSONPostProcessorGui.class.getName());

        // Response Assertion
        ResponseAssertion ra = new ResponseAssertion();
        ra.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, AssertionGui.class.getName());
        ra.setName(JMeterUtils.getResString("assertion_title"));
        ra.setTestFieldResponseCode();
        ra.setToEqualsType();
        ra.addTestString("200");

        // Create a loop controller
        LoopController loopController = new LoopController();
        loopController.setLoops(10);
        loopController.setFirst(true);
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, LoopController.class.getName());
        loopController.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, LoopControlPanel.class.getName());
        loopController.initialize();

        // Create a thread group
        ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup();
        threadGroup.setName("First Thread Group");
        threadGroup.setNumThreads(2);
        threadGroup.setRampUp(1);
        threadGroup.setSamplerController(loopController);
        threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ThreadGroup.class.getName());
        threadGroup.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, ThreadGroupGui.class.getName());

        // Create a test plan
        TestPlan testPlan = new TestPlan("Test Plan");
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, TestPlan.class.getName());
        testPlan.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestPlanGui.class.getName());
        testPlan.setUserDefinedVariables((Arguments) new ArgumentsPanel().createTestElement());

        // Add the test plan to our hash tree, this is the top level of our test
        testPlanTree.add(testPlan);

        // Create another hash tree and add the thread group to our test plan
        HashTree threadGroupHashTree = testPlanTree.add(testPlan, threadGroup);

        // Create a hash tree to add the post processor to
        HashTree httpSamplerOneTree = new HashTree();
        httpSamplerOneTree.add(httpSamplerOne, jsonExtractor);
        httpSamplerOneTree.add(httpSamplerOne, ra);

        // Add the http sampler to the hash tree that contains the thread group
        threadGroupHashTree.add(httpSamplerOneTree);
        threadGroupHashTree.add(httpSamplerTwo);

        SaveService.saveTree(testPlanTree, new FileOutputStream(jmeterHome + "/bin/FirstTest.jmx"));

        // Summariser
        Summariser summariser = null;
        String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summarise.names", "summary response");
        if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
            summariser = new Summariser(summariserName);
        }

        ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summariser);
        testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

        // Write to a file
        ResultCollector rc = new ResultCollector();
        rc.setEnabled(true);
        rc.setErrorLogging(false);
        rc.isSampleWanted(true);
        SampleSaveConfiguration ssc = new SampleSaveConfiguration();
        ssc.setTime(true);
        ssc.setAssertionResultsFailureMessage(true);
        ssc.setThreadCounts(true);
        rc.setSaveConfig(ssc);
        rc.setFilename(jmeterHome + "/bin/FirstTest.jtl");
        testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], rc);

        // Configure
        jm.configure(testPlanTree);

        // Run
        jm.run();
    }
}
```

I get a following error for SaveService.SaveTree in line 120

```
Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: No converter available
---- Debugging information ----
message             : No converter available
type                : java.util.IdentityHashMap
converter           : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.SerializableConverter
message[1]          : Unable to make private void java.util.IdentityHashMap.readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.ClassNotFoundException accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @30c7da1e
converter[1]        : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
message[2]          : Unable to make field transient java.util.Set java.util.AbstractMap.keySet accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @30c7da1e
-------------------------------
```

I searched on the web for the solution but was unable to find one.
I updated Jmeter, added necessary plugins via plugin manager, added jmeter dependencies to gradle in the project we use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copied and pasted their code you forgot to copy and paste the project configuration, in the article they use Java 8 and you're using Java 9 or higher.

[image]

If you want to try to replicate the behaviour you should add [this line](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.6.2/bin/jmeter#L129) from jmeter startup script to your project runtime settings.

I know you like to copy and paste so I'll make the process easier for you and copy and paste it here just in case:

```
--add-opens java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/sun.swing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/javax.swing.text.html=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.desktop/java.awt.font=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.X11=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.desktop/sun.awt.shell=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Also it appears that guys from Octoperf also like to copy and paste content from BlazeMeter from 2014 without mentioning the original authors:

- [JMeter Command Line Overview: 5 Ways To Launch a Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-command-line)
- [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src/master/)

You might also be interested in [jmeter-java-dsl](https://abstracta.github.io/jmeter-java-dsl/) project which provides more handy API for creating JMeter tests in Java, saving them to .jmx and running them.

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem :) 
jmeter dsl project looks handy so I will give it a go